# Android, Layout: How do I get my button to overlay existing layout in axml?

Tags: android, xml

As for most of you: we design our screens for our app in photoshop and then try to transfer them into Visual Studio.

This is a screenshot of our app FROM PHOTOSHOP:

[image]

You could imagine, the further we go the harder it gets. The center screen was easy but the left and right one - oh boy...

Anyway, today I'm here for the right one.

As you can see, there are these headlines such as: "Show Us Love For Asia".
This whole box shows a photo, a headline, a few extra infos AND:
a profile picture.

The whole is a scrollview and the white bars underneath each box are actually pngs. The reason is, that we need them to be equally sized on each different platform. Anyway - the profile picture is overlapping the picture box and the white divider png in between the picture boxes.

And here is the question: how the hell would we implement that into our axml?

As far as the screen is, this is it in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutadventure"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="17"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#23313e"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sub_category_europe"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:id="@+id/imgSubchallenge" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:id="@+id/txtSub"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:text="Positive Thinking"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:src="@drawable/dotted_line_challenges" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="35"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bar2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Done"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Exp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalChallenges"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalChallengesDone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Done"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalXP"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Exp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="82.5"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/scrlview">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/linlayout"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

So you probably see the dilemma: the profile picture is halfway in one column of the scrollview and halfway in another column.

Can you provide any help for that? THANKS SO MUCH :)

Comment: Forget linearlayouts, embrace relativelayouts!!

Comment: hell nooo :D !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i hope this will help you. This is for only **"Show Us Love For Asia"** one item only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try later today :)

Comment: Just tested it  and got it to work! I needed to replace the android.support.v4 to a simple imageview but that did the trick!" can you explain how and why this works? Thanks!

Comment: I feel happy that you got your answer. As per your requirement that you need to set `imageview` or `Circle View` exact between two View so by using `FramLayout` we can overlap control one over another. It is possible with `RelativeLayout` also but `FramLayout` is better to use. For More detail please read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html